# URL Rewrite best practice & how to set it up with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a small personal project I'm working on, and before I get too deep into it, I'd like to get some opinions here on the best practices regarding the set up and URL scheme... and how I might set up the .htaccess rewrites for the following. My questions are:

1. Is the below set up the best way to manage user information in a small user profile setup?
2. I have worked out how to get the subdomain working for the rewrite username.domain.com with wildcard subdomains and  **`httpd.conf`** file set up... but I am stuck on the rest of the scheme seen below. Basically, a user profile will always result in `username.domain.com` and then appended with the various pages within their account (photos, videos, notes etc). How would I set up the **`.htaccess`** rewrites to accommodate this? I really appreciate any advice here. I have done a ton of research here on stackoverflow, and on other sites, but I can't find a decent explanation to achieve this.

Thanks for any help.

`www.domain.com/profile.php?u=username` --> `username.domain.com`

`www.domain.com/photos.php?u=username` --> `username.domain.com/photos`

`www.domain.com/photos.php?u=username&a=album` --> `username.domain.com/photos/album`

`www.domain.com/photos.php?u=username&a=album1&p=photoid` --> `username.domain.com/photos/album1/photoid`

`www.domain.com/settings.php?u=username` --> `username.domain.com/settings`

etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed setup looks fine to me. Here are some rules for .htaccess (make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled and AllowOverride All set in your httpd.conf):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/profile.php?u=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^photos/?$ http://www.domain.com/photos.php?u=%1

RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]+)/?$ http://www.domain.com/photos.php?u=%1&a=$1

RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ http://www.domain.com/photos.php?u=%1&a=$1&p=$2

RewriteRule ^settings/?$ http://www.domain.com/settings.php?u=%1
```

Comment: You're welcome - glad to hear it worked. Re. slow/fast - this shouldn't slow you down much, if at all. It's OK to have basic rewrites in your .htaccess. It's only when there are complex rules or many rules that it slows things down. If you want though you ould eventually migrate these over to httpd.conf .

Comment: Great! Really appreciate the advice

Answer (score 0):

Wich server do you use? And first of all use rewrites in the config file of your server, not htaccess, htaccess slows the server down.

Edit: Iam not shure about the speed, but as far as i remember htaccess slows down apache, i dont know about how much. Iam sry you have to google that :)

Comment: Im on a Unix server. Unfortunately I don't have direct access to the config file as I am on a shared server. Once I get set up properly I will migrate to a dedicated server. Is the config set up significantly faster than htaccess?